# Source map is not working in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, source-maps

First of all, I have enabled source maps in chrome.
Then I go to http://dev.fontdragr.com/ which use source maps, I found the map file is also dowloaded,but still the minified source was displayed in the source tab.

Chromium version:
`version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.10 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2`)

I have also tried to use firefox, it still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your build? `31.0.1650.57 m` on Win8 works for me (I can view `fontfacecss.js`)

Are you attempting to open the minified source or the original files? Chrome will allow you to do both.